# cordova: How to develop web services for cordova mobile application

Tags: web-services, cordova, rest

i am developing mobile application for one of my web app. After long search on google i found cordova to be the best for cross platform mobile app development. I am developing cordova based front end with ionic framework. I want to know which web service is the best one to communicate between mobile app & server. I am familier with REST for webapp but have no idea for mobile.

Note: My database is on server & i am communicating through web services only so no local database resides on mobile.

Thanks in advance for quick response.

Comment: you use the same webservices for webapp and for mobile

Comment: That web service is in PHP with JSON. will it support to cordova application???

Comment: i just have to add angular JS to work with my existing PHP & JSON service to work with mobile app. Thanks to @jcesarmobile for quick response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well angularJS with PHP & JSON object combination would be the best combination for the web services to develop for cordova application. Angular js used for cordova is the best to put at web service level too with PHP.

I found my answer after long search....:-)